# Pelican: Como definir o layout de cada página semelhante ao Jekyll?

Tags: python, ruby

Eu uso [Jekyll](https://github.com/jekyll) em meu [site](http://www.devfuria.com.br/), vou parar de usar por essa [razão](https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll-help/issues/123).
Eu queria migrar para o [Pelican](https://github.com/getpelican/pelican) mas travei nos layouts. O problema é o seguinte:

No Jekyll eu posso **em cada página (page)** definir o layout, ou melhor, dizer (apontar) qual será o layout, Ex:

```
foo1.md
---
layout: modelo-a
---

foo2.md
---
layout: modelo-b
---

foo3.md
---
layout: modelo-c
---
```

Eu não descobri como fazer isso no Pelican, alguém sabe como?

Aquela variável de configuração `TEMPLATE_PAGES`...

```
TEMPLATE_PAGES = {'src/books.html': 'dest/books.html',
              'src/resume.html': 'dest/resume.html',
              'src/contact.html': 'dest/contact.html'}
```

... não me serve porque eu tenho mais de 100 páginas e o número está crescendo, imagine como ficaria o negócio!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O template da página pode ser escolhido junto com o resto dos metadados da página, tipo:

```
Title: Meu Artigo
Date: 2014-09-18 10:20
Modified: 2014-09-18 18:40
Tags: opiniao, tecnologia
Category: artigos
Slug: meu-artigo
Authors: Flavio Micheletti
Summary: Como especificar o template em cada página do Pelican
Template: modelo-a

Para escolher o template em cada página você precisa...
```

Comment: Oi Sergio, obrigado pela resposta. Eu vou testar e se tudo der certo, volto aqui para fechar o tópico.